# En PHP, ¿se pueden inicializar propiedades estáticas por medio del método constructor?

Tags: php

En relación a las propiedades estáticas, los ejemplos que he visto siempre declaran e inicializan la propiedades directamente en la clase, por lo que me pregunto si es posible inicializar estas propiedades a través de un método constructor o un setter.

Gracias.

Comment: [Está claramente explicado en la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php), conviene que consultes allí siempre. Realmente, querer inicializar una propiedad estática mediante un método no tiene ningún sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, es posible aunque las variables estáticas existen previo a la instanciación de la clase como tal y por tanto siempre que sean públicas o tenga algún método para poder acceder a la variable se podrá acceder a ellas sin instanciar un objeto de dicha clase con `Test::$var`.

En el siguiente ejemplo:

1. `$setted`: Es una variable estática pública accesible sin métodos y que ya tiene un valor
2. `$test`: La variable estática `test` es privada y solo se puede acceder a ella con `Test::getTest()`. `$test` toma un valor cuando se instancia un objeto de esta clase aunque puede cambiar su estado usando `Test::setTest()`.

```js
<?php

class Test {

    public static $setted = 'oldValue';
    private static $test;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$test = 'newValueConstruct';
    }

    public static function setTest (string $value) {
        self::$test = $value;
    }

    public static function getTest() {
        return self::$test;
    }


}

Test::setTest('newValue');
echo Test::$setted; // <-- 'oldValue'
echo Test::getTest(); // <-- 'newValue'

$test = new Test();
echo Test::getTest(); // <-- 'newValueConstruct'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Acabo de ver que el error que estaba cometiendo en mi código era de sintaxis... Pretendía llamar a una propiedad estática con el mismo estilo de sintaxis que una no estática `$self::propiedad` (siguiendo la estructura sintáctica del `$this`)
Claro, me daba error. La forma correcta es `self::$propiedad`

Muchas gracias por tu aclaración. Muy completa